# NSDictionary literals causing crash when used with setTitleTextAttributes

Tags: objective-c, literals

I am converting my xcode project to modern objective c. In my AppDelegate, previously, I have this code:

```
- (void)customizeAppearance
{
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:barButtonFont, UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Following, the literal way to create NSDictionary with @{keys : value}, I changed it to:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeFont: barButtonFont} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This one change crashes my system. The error output is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0]'

Does anyone know why and what I can do to fix it?

I can ignore it but then it would bite me later on as I will forget. I do want to change my entire project to modern objective c and won't have to remember in the future why one code is not 'modern'.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess your `barButtonFont` is `nil`.

Comment: UIFont *barButtonFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica CE" size:12.0];

Comment: Your code does return `nil`. Use this code `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]` to get Helvetica font.

Comment: Is it Helvetica by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `barButtonFont` is `nil`, (probably because you don't have a font called *Helvetica CE* available). This problem is only exposed when you move to the literal syntax, because "Neither keys nor values can have the value nil in containers. If the compiler can prove that a key or value is nil at compile time, then a warning will be emitted. Otherwise, a runtime error will occur."

There is more detail here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 2):

For setting the attributes you need to set it for both states.

Try this snippet of code:

```
 NSDictionary* textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:45.0] forKey: UITextAttributeFont];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: textAttributes
                                            forState: UIControlStateDisabled];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: textAttributes
                                            forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Implement this in Appdelegate

For more details you can refer this answer as well.

[UIBarButtonItem appearance setTitleTextAttributes does not affects UIControlStateDisabled state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718243/uibarbuttonitem-appearance-settitletextattributes-does-not-affects-uicontrolstat)